# make directory with bash builtin

Tags: shell, terminal, cygwin, mkdir

I am writing bash script for Windows 7 and have limitation to `bash.exe`

`mkdir` -p does not work (command not found)

I am looking for any replacement/cheat with bash builtins. (the `-p` flag is not mandatory, could do this with a loop instead)

There is some idea to [Transform a file into directory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/118085/transform-a-directory-into-file-or-a-file-into-directory) or some other nice hack only a expert will know. This question is not about how to fix a missing mkdir binary, but about reducing dependencies of (broken) core utils.

this are the available bash builtins:

> & (( . : [ [[ alias bg bind break builtin caller case cd command compgen complete compopt continue coproc declare dirs disown echo enable eval exec exit export false fc fg for function getopts hash help history if jobs kill let local logout mapfile popd printf pushd pwd read readarray readonly return select set shift shopt source suspend test time times trap true type typeset ulimit umask unalias unset until wait while {

if not possible with bash builtins there are some external utils available. There is already one example which depends on `cp`
[Create a new folder using bash without mkdir command](https://serverfault.com/questions/520561/create-a-new-folder-using-bash-without-mkdir-command)
this is all i have:

> bash blobpack blobunpack bzip2 cat chmod clear cpio cut dd dhtbsign dos2unix dumpimage elftool expr file find futility grep gzip hexdump kernel_dump loki_tool ls lz4 lzop mac2unix mboot md5sum mkbootimg mkimage mkmtkhdr mv printf pxa-mkbootimg pxa-unpackbootimg rkcrc rm sed stat sudo tail tar touch unix2dos unix2mac unpackbootimg unpackelf xz

Note: I have edited the question to clarify the needs.

Comment: As far as I know there is no bash built-in that creates a directory. You have to use an external program.

Comment: Show your code with mkdir command.

Comment: get the originator of this bastardized `cygwin/bash` 'installation' to add more binaries (eg, `mkdir.exe`) or better yet, build your own (ie, install a full version of `cygwin/bash` and then pick-n-choose the binaries you want for your reduced-/bastardized `cygwin/bash` installation)

Comment: i could add this myself or just add busybox. but i could only do it on my own pc. there are lot of such reduzed bundles (for example Odinatrix) and the goal is to make universal script with reduzed dependencies. maybe i am writing .bat file for creating folders, because windows mkdir works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This trick can be helpful to run Windows `md` shell builtin from within bash script

```
echo -e 'md %*\r' > mkdir.bat
./mkdir.bat test
```

Answer (score 1):

If I'm reading the contents of that `pastebin.com` link correctly, this is not a true/complete `cygwin` installation.

That link shows the following (in a windows environment):

```
PATH = ... C:\Android\bash ...                 # this is not where cygwin is typically installed though, yeah, you could override the default installation directory

C:\Users\mint>bash                             # this is not how `cygwin/bash` is invoked
bash-4.1$ 

bash-4.1$ ls /cygdrive/c/Android/bash          # full cygwin install does not throw everything under a single directory like this:
bash.exe          ... snip ...      mv.exe
```

At this point this doesn't appear to be an actual `cygwin` installation but rather some sort of reduced/incomplete/bastardized `bash` installation under the `C:\Android\bash` directory.

Where/How did OP 'install' the contents under the `C:\Android\bash` directory?

For comparison purposes (my windows machine):

```
# cygwin installation directory:

C:\cygwin64>dir
 Volume in drive C is Windows7
 Volume Serial Number is xxxx-yyyy

 Directory of C:\cygwin64

11/06/2020  12:29    <DIR>          .
11/06/2020  12:29    <DIR>          ..
03/30/2021  16:08    <DIR>          bin
05/25/2019  17:15            53,342 Cygwin-Terminal.ico
05/25/2019  18:46                95 Cygwin.2.bat
05/25/2019  17:15                88 Cygwin.bat
05/25/2019  17:15           157,097 Cygwin.ico
02/08/2021  13:01    <DIR>          dev
02/04/2021  12:06    <DIR>          etc
02/26/2021  16:35    <DIR>          home
02/02/2021  11:34    <DIR>          lib
07/12/2020  17:28    <DIR>          sbin
11/06/2020  12:29    <DIR>          srv
05/07/2021  07:46    <DIR>          tmp
02/02/2021  11:34    <DIR>          usr
05/25/2019  17:15    <DIR>          var
               6 File(s)        210,622 bytes
              12 Dir(s)  20,305,154,048 bytes free

C:\cygwin64\bin>dir
 Volume in drive C is Windows7
 Volume Serial Number is xxxx-yyyy

 Directory of C:\cygwin64\bin

03/30/2021  16:08    <DIR>          .
03/30/2021  16:08    <DIR>          ..
... snip ...
02/03/2017  14:40            37,395 base64.exe
02/03/2017  14:40            29,715 basename.exe
01/27/2017  14:13           739,859 bash.exe               # bash binary
01/27/2017  14:13             7,291 bashbug
10/17/2014  17:00            81,949 bc.exe
... snip ...
12/20/2020  17:01            11,564 mintheme
02/03/2017  14:40            62,995 mkdir.exe              # mkdir binary
02/03/2017  14:40            29,715 mkfifo.exe
08/22/2020  14:00            21,523 mkgroup.exe
... snip ...
2/19/2020  11:37                30 zstdless
2/03/2017  14:41            64,019 [.exe
           1130 File(s)    541,740,761 bytes               # 1100+ binaries in this directory
              2 Dir(s)  20,305,154,048 bytes free

# example cygwin session startup

C:\cygwin64\bin\mintty.exe -i /Cygwin-Terminal.ico -

     # user has option to startup a few different tty's;
     # actual OS is determined from /etc/passwd entry (/usr/bin/bash in my case)
```

At this point if OP wants to run `cygwin/bash` then I'd suggest installing an actual `cygwin` environment (see [cygwin.org](https://cygwin.org) ), making sure to also install the `bash` package.

As for how to simulate `mkdir` with ... whatever is installed under `C:\Android\bash` ... *shrug* ... have the originator pull more of the binaries (eg, `mkdir.exe`) from a complete `cygwin/bash` installation?

----------------------- previous answer (before reviewing the contents of the `pastebin.com` link)

I'm wondering if this could be an issue of an incomplete/corrupted `cygwin/bash` installation or an invalid `$PATH` ... ?

From my `cygwin` environment:

```
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.4.12(3)-release (x86_64-unknown-cygwin)

$ which mkdir
/usr/bin/mkdir

$ command -v mkdir
/usr/bin/mkdir

$ mkdir --version
mkdir (GNU coreutils) 8.26
Packaged by Cygwin (8.26-2)
```

Does `/usr/bin/mkdir` exist?

What is returned when running `find / -name mkdir*`?

If you can find `mkdir(.exe)` then the next check would be for the location/path also being defined in `$PATH` ...

Comment: then it sounds like an incomplete `cygwin` and/or `cygwin/bash` installation since `/usr/bin` (and `/usr/bin/mkdir`) should exist.

Comment: thx but question is about mkdir alternative not about cygwin core utils. i have edited the question and deleted the misleading word cygwin

Comment: the main issue still exists ... someone ripped a select list of binaries from a `cygwin/bash` installation and then slammed them into a single directory; since there are thousands of binaries in a complete `cygwin` installation you would best be served by going to the source of this bastardized-cygwin installation and ask them to add more binaries to the mix (eg, `mkdir.exe`)

Comment: if you're going to be pushing a script out to the remote machine ... why not push out the additional `cygwin/bash` binaries that you need?

Comment: yeah that's maybe easiest workaround just bundle x86 busybox within a zip - will go for it, thx!

Comment: busybox has other limitations (only ash no bash) so have to rewrite the whole script now. maybe i write plain .bat without any dependencies now. But curious about why inside bash script i can call windows files like adb.exe but not windows md/mkdir command. if it is a shell builtin it should work *'cmd.exe mkdir test'* at least

Comment: is windows' `mkdir` a binary or a builtin? if a builtin ... this would seem to make sense ... windows **binaries** (eg, `adb.exe`) are available because (according to the info in that `pastebin.com` link) the windows **PATH** entries are maintained upon calling `bash.exe` directly, but since you've invoked a new shell (ie, `bash`) this would tend to disable any builtin's from the 'parent' shell (ie, the windows shell); another option (`busybox/ash` vs `windows/bat`), and assuming you know this modified `bash` env is on all remote machines ...

Comment: would be to: **a)** install a full copy of `cygwin/bash` on your machine, **b)** find/copy all of the `cygwin/bash` binaries that you need (eg, `mkdir.exe`) and **c)** push this additional set of `cygwin/bash` binaries with your script; yeah, this is getting (more) convoluted but, this is just an extension of trying to work with the incomplete/bastardized `cygwin` 'installation'